# 2d gif over 3d object

Tags: modeling, rendering, edges, 2d

When I place my 2d gif over a 3d static object like a book, it works but the edges are zigzaged after I render it in my custom developed programme. There is no requirement to view the final gif in 360 view, just want the gif to be placed wrapped around the static model for example ebook.ebook model template was also designed in house.

Can I use blender to test this by importing my gif and static 3d ebook model and then render it as a gif again and wish the edges are smooth?[image]
Basically when gif is rendered with transparent background,  I see these edges, with coloured bg, its fine

Comment: Could you make the question more detailed like adding screenshots and files etc.,

Comment: Updated with screenshot